# Where does this “pyvenv.cfg” file exist?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I give a quotation of `site` module documentation below and i am not aware where “pyvenv.cfg” file actually exists.Does it just exist in a directory one level higher than `sys/executable`'s ?

> If a file named **“pyvenv.cfg”** exists one directory ***above*** sys.executable, sys.prefix and sys.exec_prefix are set to that directory and it is also checked for site-packages (sys.base_prefix and sys.base_exec_prefix will always be the “real” prefixes of the Python installation). If “pyvenv.cfg” (a bootstrap configuration file) contains the key “include-system-site-packages” set to anything other than “false” (case-insensitive), the system-level prefixes will still also be searched for site-packages; otherwise they won’t.

Comment: Often, to find where a file is search for, i use `strace`. Provides somehow cryptic messages but you will locate the files you need.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't exist unless it is created.

> ***If*** ...

And if it is created, it should be in the same directory as the executable or one directory above as per [PEP 405](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/).

Comment: This situation is somewhat different from PEP 405's, within which `sys.prefix` and `sys.base_prefix` are computed in a more complicated manner.